# How to ignore warnings from dpkg-query when it doesn't find anything?

Tags: debian, dpkg, output

In a case where I write a query for dpkg-query to list me some package, I would like it to return me the package name if it finds something. If it doesn't find anything, I don't want it to output: `no package found matching {package-name}` I would like it to output nothing at all.

The reason for this is because my query is in a script and if it returns that my script breaks. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redirect `dpkg-query`'s stderr to `/dev/null` to silence the error message, as in `dpkg-query --list <package> 2>/dev/null`.